# screen readers to read content when element is expanded

Tags: accessibility, accordion, expand, contract

I have a couple of div elements with a title and a read more link. When a user clicks on the read more, the div element expands, showing the content, and the "read more" link converts to a "read less" link. When a user clicks the read less link, the div element contracts showing the read more link again.

The element works as it should, but I am trying to implement accessibility.

1. I toggle the div's aria-expanded attribute between true/false depending on whether the div tag is
   expanded or contracted
2. I add an aria-label to the less link with the body content of the div

The latter works when I tab off the link and tab back on the Less link. Also, when I tab back in, I can use the enter key to contract and expand the div element, and only then screen readers will read the content
I tried setting the focus on the less link using JavaScript when the div expands, but that doesn't work.

How do I ensure screen readers read the content on the div element initial expands?

My query is similar to accordions. I found two examples of accessibility accordions and noticed that my screen reader (NVDA) does not read the initial hidden content when the answer becomes visible in both cases.

[Accessible accordion example 1](https://examples.hassellinclusion.com/accordion/accessible-accordion-example.html)

[Accessible accordion example 2](http://web-accessibility.carnegiemuseums.org/code/accordions/) (example at the bottom of page)

Comment: what is the point or the `aria-label` on the less link first of all? Second are you familiar with how to use a screen reader, it won't automatically read the content of a div when you open it, you press the modifier and down key to read the next part, but depending on how you manage your read more link you may need to do some focus management etc. Do you want to create a fiddle with what you have done so far and that way we can give you pointers as at the moment it is difficult to understand what you have done right and what you may (or may not) have missed.

Comment: Thanks @GrahamRitchie.   I found a solution what I am after for using aria-live and following [this example](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/en/web/components-examples/make-a-screen-reader-talk/)

Comment: Don't use `aria-live` for this, that will be an awful experience for screen reader users and I can almost guarantee it will end up worse than your current implementation. Create a fiddle and I will help and as I said focus management is probably your better option.